# Recursively expand and search pattern of specific subdirectories

Tags: python, path, filepath, subdirectory, wildcard-expansion

I'm looking for an option to search specific subdirectories in python.

For instance a directory structure like this:

```
some_files/
     common/
     2009/
     2010/
     2011/
     ...
```

I only want to search for in the subdirectories that start with a 2, so that it must be something like 'some_files/2*'. I think it must be possible using glob.glob and os.walk(), but I can't get it to work.

Now i use:

```
files = [os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(d)
                for f in files if f.endswith(ext)]
```

but this doesn't fit the specific needs.

Can someone help me out, would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with something like `and os.path.join('some_files', '2') in dirpath`?

Comment: The tool I'm developing looks for specific files in user specified places. These places are specified in a config file. So they can say, you may look in this folder (some_files/), then it searches all the subdirectories as well. I want to give the user an option to only search in specific subdirectories, with a statement like somefiles/2*. If i understand it correctly the option you give won't support that. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? It just checks whether the specified string is found in the path string.

Comment: What do you want to do with files contained in directories such as 'some_files/2011/foo' and 'some_files/bar/2011'?

Comment: You meant *"(recursively) expand and search (wildcarded) pattern of specific subdirectories"*. That's a lot more than just saying *"specific subdirectories"*. I edited the title for clarity.

Comment: 'some_files/2011/foo' must be searched as well, 'some_files/bar/2011' should not be searched since 'bar' doesn't start with a 2. Thank smci for the new title, that indeed covers it better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use glob with dirpath to find matching directories:

```
from glob import iglob
import os

files = []
ext = "py"
for dirpath, dirnames, file in os.walk(path):
    match = next(iglob(os.path.join(dirpath, "2*")),"")
    if match:
        files.extend(iglob(os.path.join(match,"*.{}".format(ext))))
print(files)
```

Or if you really want a list comp:

```
files = [f for dirpath, dirnames, file in os.walk(path) for f in
         iglob(os.path.join(next(iglob(os.path.join(dirpath, "2*")),
                                 '\\\\'), "*.{}".format(ext)))]
print(files)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this using [pathlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib) (*which is now part of the Python3 std lib*):

```
from pathlib import Path

for subpath in Path().glob("2*):
    for file in subpath.glob("*.ext"):
        # ...
```

**Update:** [pathlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib) is also available for Python 2.x (*it was back-ported and published to the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypi)*). Simply:

```
$ pip install pathlib
```

Comment: *pathlib* is also available for 2.7+, just needs to be manually installed